# Dismissing UIPickerView with Done button on UIToolBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I am just trying out which is better with regards to dismissing a `UIPickerView` -- a button on the navigation bar or a "Done" button on a toolbar above the picker view. I have implemented both buttons, and I am trying to dismiss the picker view and resign first responder.

How can I dismiss the `UIPickerView` with the "Done" Button on the toolbar?

This is my code for the `UIToolBar`:

```
UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent = YES;
keyboardDoneButtonView.tintColor = nil;
[keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                               action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked:)] autorelease];

[keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];

textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Without having tried this myself: What exactly is your question/problem? The pickerView does not disappear? If this doesn't work you could animate it downwards manually and call a removeFromSuperview I guess. Does that make sense?

Comment: i'm going to try and replicate this if possible. if i can get a working code, i'll share what i have with you

Comment: pickerview.inputAccessoryItem is not working.. why so?

Comment: I found this blog which shows how to implement it with a done button - http://asanhussain.blogspot.in/2012/11/uipickerview-in-uiactionsheet-for-iphone.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got it working on my end, though I'm sure my test app is much much simpler in comparison, so hopefully the structure still works for yours.

In essence, this is all I did.  I have a `UIPickerView`, `UIDatePickerView`, and `UITextField` set up in IB.  The pickerView's `dataSource` and `delegate` are both linked to File's Owner, as is the `delegate` of the textField.

In my header, I have them all declared with the following structure

```
UISomething *object;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISomething *object;
```

I've also got the protocols linked (`<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>`).  In the implementation file, everything is synthesized.  Then in `viewDidLoad`, I have this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent = YES;
    keyboardDoneButtonView.tintColor = nil;
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                                   action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked:)] autorelease];

    [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];

    textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
    [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
    [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

When the textField becomes active, I call this

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
}
```

Then finally, there's the action method

```
- (IBAction)pickerDoneClicked:(id)sender {
    [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
    [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This all works for me.  Everything gets displayed and removed as it should.  So with any luck, this will do the trick for you too

Comment: Very neat workaround. Why inputAccessoryView is read-only in UIPickerView only Apple know, but this is a great solution. Thanks Slev. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)pickerDoneClicked:(id)sender {
    [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Or if you want to dismiss it with an animation, change the view frame with UIView animations and then remove it from superview.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

pickerView.frame = outOfScreenFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

where outOfScreenFrame is somewhere outside your UIApplication window.

Comment: I have tried that. I get error Unrecognized selector sent to instance '1290837'

Comment: Not sure what you did wrong as I wasn't typing your code exactly as slev did, but I hope you managed to figure it out! :)

Answer (score 2):

In Swift

```
lazy var inputToolbar: UIToolbar = {
    var toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = .Default
    toolbar.translucent = true
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "inputToolbarDonePressed")
    var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    toolbar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolbar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolbar
}()

func inputToolbarDonePressed() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**UITextFieldDelegate**

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.inputAccessoryView = inputToolbar

    return true
}
```