# UITabBarController inside a UIViewController = viewDidAppear: not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I start off with a login screen.  Then after the user logs in I load a Viewcontroller with UITabBArController in it.  The problem is viewdidAppear: does not get called for any of the individual viewControllers in the tabBarController.

I have a feeling that this is not the best programming practise so does anyone have any ideas how to improve the structure of my code or how to fix my problem ?

Comment: This seems like it would be fine, could you post the code you use in the viewController that controls the tab bar?

Comment: How are you adding the tab bar controller "inside" the view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess your trouble here comes from incorrect use of UIViewController and UITabBarController.

UITabBarController exists as a container for multiple view controllers. It probably should not, itself, be contained. It's designed to sit at the top of a view controller hierarchy. So step one is probably to re-arrange your application so that the UITabBarController is no longer under anything else and see if that straightens you out.

After that, slev's approach of presenting the login view sounds like the right one.

Comment: In iOS5 there is supposed to be API support for customizing a ui view controller such that it can act as a container for things such as UITabBarController.

Comment: Sorry this is not correct. UITabBarController can be nested. Just make sure that you call [super viewWillAppear] if you override its own method.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem because I was subclassing also UITabBarControler where I have overridden viewDidAppear without calling [super viewDidAppear:...]

After calling this, viewDidAppear was called also inside sub-view-controller.

Comment: Same issue for me - I guess it is considered best practice to always leave the [super viewDidSomething] on the first line in the method, and then add your code below? Hence leaving out the base call could mess up something in the call hierarchy?- Would anyone care to comment on this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not make an app which is TabBarController-based, then immediately call a modal screen at app start (for your login)? After you're done with the login, just dismiss it to allow the TabBarController to become key window.

Comment: Any chance of helping me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509078/dismissing-uipickerview-with-done-button-uitoolbar-help

Comment: @Legolas. yeah dude, sure.  i was looking at it earlier and thought the other person had the right answer already, but didn't know it'd give you that exception error

Comment: I basically have two pickerviews. 1 DatePickerView and another PickerView with 3 components. Clicking the textField brings them up. For resigning them, I use `[textField resignFirstResponder]`. This works for DatePickerView and not the other pickerview (which throws errors)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually call viewdidAppear on the subviewcontrollers: when it's called on the rootviewcontroller also call subviewcontroller's ones manually.