# iOS 5 Picker View update based on selection?

Tags: iphone, ios, picker

I am working on a project where I want to have a picker view with 3 columns. 
In the first column I want the user to select a letter. 
Once the letter is selected I want the second column to update with a list of last names that start with that letter. When a last name is selected I want the third column to update with a list of first names who have the selected last name. 
Can this even be done? Help!?

Answer (score 1):

Get the letter that they selected using this pickerview delegate method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
```

You could load the next picker at this point but it would be better to populate the next picker when the done button on each picker is selected:

This is a nice SO post that describes how to use picker views very well: [Dismissing UIPickerView with Done button on UIToolBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509078/dismissing-uipickerview-with-done-button-on-uitoolbar)