# UIToolbar not responding in Custom UITableViewCell with UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I've searched this for a while but can't find anything quite the same.

I have a UITableView, and when a certain row is selected, I insert another row below.
The inserted row is a custom tableviewcell which hold a UIPickerView.
The pickerview works fine, and when an item is selected it can trigger the notification, sending selected info back to the tableviewcontroller, and then remove the "pickerviewcell". All good there.
But this isn't ideal if the user wants to scroll back and forth on the uipickerview. So I've added a uitoolbar to the uipickerview with a Cancel & Done button.

But the Cancel and Done buttons never get fired.

From other items I have read, they talk about UIFirstResponder etc etc, but they are all related to making the uipickerview an inputaccessoryview for a uitextfield. But that is not what I am doing.

I've tried doing it all in code and via Storyboards, with the same results each time.

Some example below..

```
// (in my CustomTableViewCell's AwakeFromNib function)
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, screenSize.width, 162))
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    pickerToolbar.translucent = true
    pickerToolbar.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    pickerToolbar.sizeToFit()

    pickerToolbar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    pickerView.addSubview(pickerToolbar)
    self.contentView.insertSubview(pickerView, atIndex: 3)

    // both these logs show correct output
    NSLog("picker subviews: %@", pickerView.subviews.description)
    NSLog("toolbar subviews: %@", pickerToolbar.subviews.description)
```

Screenshot example:
By clicking on the "To" cell, the new cell is inserted which has the picker. The picker works fine by itself. But the Cancel button doesn't get triggered. It has an IBAction linked to it from Storyboard.
Clicking any cell also closes/removes the pickercell correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made a picker within a UITextview and I using

```
 -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
 [textField resignFirstResponder];

return NO;
```

and then dismissing the keyboard with

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard {
[_date resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

where _date was my UITextfield property

[Dismissing UIPickerView with Done button on UIToolBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509078/dismissing-uipickerview-with-done-button-on-uitoolbar)

this is a really good post I found on this topic as well! I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this isn't what I am after. I am not using the picker as an inputaccessoryview or as a firstresponder. It is just a subview in a tableviewcell and I need it's uitoolbar's Cancel button to be triggered, which will then hide/remove the cell from view.